# SQL Server Nested Query Performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, nested

I need some help writing this query for SQL Server.  The nested part makes this query take almost a minute to run on 27,000 records.  I think it needs a temp table, but I have not done this before.  Can someone give me an idea how I might do this?

```
SELECT  
r.ID,
r.CloseDate,
r.RepairOrderStatus 'Repair Status',
p.PartNumber ModInPN,
p.PartDescription ModInDesc,
pr.RMANumber,
c.FullName OpsTech,
    (SELECT COUNT (*)
    FROM dbo.TestPartsReplaced tpr
    WHERE tpr.RepairID = r.ID) Qty
FROM dbo.RepairTicket r LEFT JOIN dbo.Parts p ON r.ModuleInPartID = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN dbo.PartReturn pr ON r.PartReturnID = pr.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact c ON c.ID = r.ContactTechID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this....

```
SELECT  
        r.ID,
        r.CloseDate,
        r.RepairOrderStatus 'Repair Status',
        p.PartNumber ModInPN,
        p.PartDescription ModInDesc,
        pr.RMANumber,
        c.FullName OpsTech,
        Qty.[Count] AS Quantity
FROM dbo.RepairTicket r LEFT JOIN dbo.Parts p ON r.ModuleInPartID = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN dbo.PartReturn pr ON r.PartReturnID = pr.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact c ON c.ID = r.ContactTechID
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT RepairID , COUNT (*) AS [Count]
            FROM dbo.TestPartsReplaced
            GROUP BY RepairID) Qty    ON  Qty.RepairID = r.ID
```

Comment: Hi M.Ali ! Can you please tell me what is the problem in OP's query and how you arrived at your answer ? I am still a newbie and I am not able to understand. Please help. Thank you. Chenqui.

Comment: That correlated sub-query in select is executed for each row returned by the Outer query. Now this sub-query in FROM clause is executed once and joined with the results returned from other tables. I reckon OP will gain some performance by putting this sub-query in from clause.

Comment: This is perfect M.Ali.  It runs as quickly as it did without the nested query.  Thank you so much; I learned so much. Mikeo